# How to improve this INSERT code with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, insert-update

I had this code:

```
for chunk in np.array_split(DataFrame, 20, axis=0):
    for i in chunk.index:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = VALUES(col1), col2 = VALUES(col2), col3 = VALUES(col3), col4 = VALUES(col4);", (chunk['col1'][i], chunk['col2'][i], chunk['col3'][i], chunk['col4'][i]))
                                          #col1 and col2 are primary keys
```

So someone told me that you didn't need to add the columns with the **primary key** after the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and that you didn't need to put the values inside the **VALUES()**

So my code is now like this:

```
for chunk in np.array_split(DataFrame, 20, axis=0):
    for i in chunk.index:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3 = col3, col4 = col4;", (chunk['col1'][i], chunk['col2'][i], chunk['col3'][i], chunk['col4'][i]))
                                          #col1 and col2 are primary keys
```

How can I **improve** this code even more?

Sorry for the mistakes and thanks in advance!

Comment: What on earth is the point of doing `col3 = col3, col4 = col4` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part of that query

Comment: @RiggsFolly Isn't this how you indicate which columns should be updated if the primary keys are duplicated? I learned like this :|

Comment: What exactly are you trying to improve?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Mainly the syntax, there are probably shorter ways to do this query, more efficient too!

Comment: How large is your array of values

Comment: @RiggsFolly I split the DataFrame into 20 chunks and the size of the chunks will depend on the number of records in the DataFrame, which I don't have a specific one!

Comment: Try the second suggestion in my answer then

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure I have seen this question before, so I will try and be a bit more helpful this time.

I am not very Python capable, so forgive any obvious syntax errors.

I assume you want to update col3 and col4 to the values you are passing to the INSERT if you get to the DUPLICATE situation, so

```
for chunk in np.array_split(DataFrame, 20, axis=0):
    for i in chunk.index:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table 
                                (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
                        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) 
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                            UPDATE col3 = %s, col4 = %s;", 
            (   
                chunk['col1'][i], chunk['col2'][i], chunk['col3'][i], chunk['col4'][i], 
                chunk['col3'][i], chunk['col4'][i])  # these 2 are for the update on dup
            )
```

If your array of data is large you can also use a prepared parameterised query. Then the database only has to compile and optimise the query once, on the first call to `.execute()` so all future executions will just pass data to an already compiled query saved in the database

```
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
# Parameterized query
sql = """ INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
               VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) 
               ON DUPLICATE KEY 
               UPDATE col3 = %s, col4 = %s"""

for chunk in np.array_split(DataFrame, 20, axis=0):
    for i in chunk.index:
        cursor.execute(sql, chunk['col1'][i], chunk['col2'][i], chunk['col3'][i], chunk['col4'][i], 
                        chunk['col3'][i], chunk['col4'][i] )
```

Again forgive any Python syntax errors

Comment: The slow parts are `INSERT .. UPDATE` itself and executing N queries instead of a batch, bulk copying or specifying multiple row values, eg `INSERT ... VALUES (%s,%s,%), (%s,%s,%s) ...`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've probably asked a similar question before, but I'm looking for ways to improve the code, your way works too!

Comment: @RiggsFolly It might help, but I'm using the pymysql package which has no support for prepared statements!

Comment: Maybe time for a change